# Sender and MessageBox oddities

Tags: vb.net

New poster here and a VB hack of sorts.

I have a windows form that contains a picture box and three textboxes.
The three textboxes (Red, Green, Blue) are used to enter a numeric value from 000 to 255 representing a color code.
The PictureBox will display the resulting color from the three TextBox values.

My validation routine ValidDecCode makes sure the values entered are within the allowable limits (000-255).

If a user enters a ‘2’ in the first position all is well.  If a user then enters a ‘6’ in the second position it will not pass my validation test.

After entering the KeyDown event I save the sender.selectionstart and the sender.text values.  After entering the ‘6’ the selectionstart will be a 1 and text contains data that has been validated, ‘2’.

Once the ‘6’ fails my validation test I display a MessageBox, reload my saved sender data, text and selectionstart.  This returns the form back to its state prior to entering the ‘6’.  The TextBox will show a ‘2’ and the cursor is placed after the ‘2’.

What I find strange is that if I comment out the MessageBox.Show() line the TextBox will show ‘26’ after failing validation.  If I comment out the reload of my sender data and not the MessageBox.Show() line, the TextBox will show ‘26’.

I would like to know why commenting out the MessageBox.Show() line does not return the form to its state prior to entering invalid data and what can I do about it.  What is it about calling the MessageBox that makes it work?

```
Private Sub RedBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles RedBox.KeyDown, GreenBox.KeyDown, BlueBox.KeyDown

    Dim InChr As String
    Dim InPos As Integer = sender.selectionstart
    Dim InText As String = sender.text


    If IsNumeric(Chr(e.KeyCode)) Then
        InChr = Chr(e.KeyValue)
            If Not ValidDecCode(InText + InChr, InPos) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid value")
                sender.text = InText
                sender.selectionstart = InPos
            End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid value")
        sender.Text = InText
        sender.selectionstart = InPos
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is an extra End If on line 16.  I believe it should be removed.

Comment: It's because you forgot to set the e.SuppressKeyPress property to True so the keypress still gets processed.  MessageBox hides this problem because it pumps a message loop.

Comment: W0052977, Edited the extra End If out.  It was only partial code and I missed it, nuts.

Hans, thanks, that did the trick for invalid numeric values.  As expected I now confronted with other logic issues.  I appreciate the input.